# OAuth2 authorization in a Office 365 Outlook Add-In using office-js-helpers

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to add OAuth authorization to a O365 Add-In targeting Outlook. As the `office-js-helpers` library looked promising. I've spend quite some time to play around with a simple plugin. However I wasn't able to make that work consistently.

#### What I did:

- I generated a new plugin skeleton using `yeoman` and the `office-generator`.
- I added simple configuration for our OAuth service and put an authorization call into the function-file.
- I attached the function to a button.
- I added a simple HTML page for the expected redirect containing the JavaScript:

  ```
  import * as OfficeHelpers from ‘@microsoft/office-js-helpers’;

  (() => {
    Office.initialize = () => {
      console.log(“initialized”);
      if (OfficeHelpers.Authenticator.isAuthDialog()) {
        console.log(“auth dialog detected”);
        return;
      }
    };
  })();
  ```

#### What I get

- When clicking the button in Outlook for Mac, the popup opens as a new window in Chrome (which happens to be my default browser). From there it seems to be unable to initialize `Office.js` and therefore to communicate back to Outlook.
- When clicking the button on Outlook for Web in Safari or Firefox it works.

#### Question

What do I need to change to get it working in native Outlook as well (I wasn't able to test on Windows yet, but this needs to work as well - of course)?